# How to change the base measure unit of font size in tinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce, font-size

The base measure unit is: PT

As you can see in the text size element on the toolbar:

[image: Font size is shown in the toolbar]

We are handling our text-size via EM units, so i tried to add an inline style on the root element, but it provokes that when you change the text the inline style is overriding the H1 text-size value, so need other solution.

I tried after that to set the styles in:
**content.css** with this tag:

```
p {
    color:red;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Everything went well, the text changed size and the color is applied but...
it seems like the toolbar wasn't updated and still show **11pt**

So i started to doubt that the style was applied.... but no it can't be, because the text is red so...

I changed the value of the font size property to **2em** and what was my surprise when i saw this on the toolbar:

[image]

So i understand now, the toolbar is converting the value assigned to the font-size property to the main unit measure: **PT** because 1em -> 11pt, 2em -> 21pt and 2.35em -> 29pt

So at this point my trip under the hood of tinymce has become a nightmare.

Can anyone tell me a config property which allows me to show **1em** (the actual value of the font-size in my P elements)?
something like `toolbar_font_size_units`

The other solution is to find the method where the text-size is converted to string and painted...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is a known bug reported at this [issue](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/4337)

You can find there the code to modify in order to implement a fix.